# How to find overlapping classes?

Tags: owl

Full ontology:

```
Prefix: : <http://www.semanticweb.org/l.smolaga/ontologies/2018/0/untitled-ontology-14#>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

Ontology: <http://www.semanticweb.org/l.smolaga/ontologies/2018/0/untitled-ontology-14>

Datatype: xsd:int

DataProperty: hasAge
    Characteristics: 
        Functional
    Domain: 
        Person
    Range: 
        xsd:int

Class: Person

Class: Student
    EquivalentTo: 
        Person
         and (hasAge some xsd:int[>= "18"^^xsd:int , <= "26"^^xsd:int])

Class: Teenager
    EquivalentTo: 
        Person
         and (hasAge some xsd:int[>= "11"^^xsd:int , <= "19"^^xsd:int])
```

I'm trying to find a way to check if two classes overlap.
For example let's consider we have an ontology with 3 classes (Person, Teenager and Student).
Teenager is equivalent to Person and hasAge some `xsd:int[>= 11, <=19 ]`
Student is equivalent to Person and hasAge some `xsd:int[>= 18, <=26 ]`

I want to check which class overlaps with Student. How I can do this using owlapi/jena ?

Comment: Well, after replacing `xsd:int[>= 11, <=19]` with `xsd:int[>= 11, <=17]`, Pellet is able to conclude that `Teenager` disjoint with `Student`...

Comment: define "overlaps" first. then develop the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will be to create an individual, say `x`, which is of type (`Person and Student and Teenager`). Invoke the reasoner and if your ontology is consistent, it means it is possible for an individual to belong to all classes. If the ontology is inconsistent, it means an individual cannot belong to all the classes simultaneously.

You should be able to do this in an ontology editor, or programmatically via the owl-api or jena.

Comment: It is equivalent to check if the class (Person and Student and Teenager) is satisfiable, with the advantage that no axioms need to be added to the ontology.